# JAVA_HOME points to wrong JDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, java-home

When running the app in Android Studio I get this error message:

[image]

As you can see the path is different.

When clicking OK the emulator starts, but nothing happens...

This is my JAVA_HOME path:

[image]

Comment: take a look [at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22749305/3326331) see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

create `JAVA_HOME` in *user variables* and *system variables* **both**!
and put a `\` at the end of path

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :)

First I added the **JAVA_HOME** -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\
, in Environment variables.

Then in Android Studio I had to right-click on the root folder of my project and select ***Open Module Settings***.

There I added the JDK path.

[image]