# Intellij 14 the supplied javaHome seems to be invalid

Tags: intellij-idea, libgdx

When first launching IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0.2 on Windows 7 x64 I received the following error when trying to import the sample libGDX gradle config:

> Intellij 14 the supplied javaHome seems to be invalid

The IDE is looking in `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0.2\jre` for the java runtime, but the files exist in a sub directory off this one: `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0.2\jre\jre`.

My solution was to copy the contents of `jre\jre` up one level to `jre`, which solved the problem - but doesn't feel like the right thing to do.

Is this an acceptable solution, or is there a 'better way' to solve this? 
It feels strange to me that the default install is not in the correct location; but there might be something environmental that I'm not quite understanding.

This was recorded as a duplicate, but it is not - it is a different product. [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) is a different product to [IntelliJ-Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Comment: Finally a solution that works! I agree that it is a weird fix but I've wasted enough time on this issue.

Comment: There is another Stackoverflow question with the answer to your issue. Here is the link to the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749200/android-studio-supplied-javahome-is-not-a-valid-folder Worked perfectly for me and from the question you have posted , it is the working solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio - supplied javaHome is not a valid folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749200/android-studio-supplied-javahome-is-not-a-valid-folder)

Comment: @Toby Allen this is not Android studio this is Intellij Idea - a different product.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have a 64-bit Java as your JAVA_HOME, run the 64-bit version on IntelliJ instead, idea64.exe in the bin directory of your IntelliJ installation; for example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0.2\bin\idea64.exe
```

Comment: what do we set this on a ubuntu ?