# IntelliJ 15 Android development Error: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid.

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-15

This is really my first attempt at getting started in developing Android. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4. I've tried looking for the solution for my problem, but I can't seem to find the exact problem that I am dealing with.

I keep getting the following error.

**Error:The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\bin\java.exe**

[image: Error:The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\bin\java.exe]

I'm really not sure where to start. How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: What is the SDK configured for the project?

Comment: It says Android API 23 Platform (Java version "1.8.0_65")

Comment: Click the edit button and check the path is correct.

Comment: I don't think that I know enough to be able to determine if it is :/

Comment: Is there a edit button next to "Project SDK" dropdown?

Answer (score -1):

You may be running the 32-bit version instead of the 64-bit version.  When I upgraded to IntelliJ 2016, it automatically put shortcuts to the 32-bit version on my desktop.  I had to change the shortcut to point to the 64-bit executable.

See [IntelliJ Gradle Plugin: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356796/intellij-gradle-plugin-the-supplied-javahome-seems-to-be-invalid)