# Android Studio Installation Error: supplied java-home seems to be invalid

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Many people got this error. I have set java variable (JAVA_HOME) and in project structure set jdk path.

But for me it's not working. Here is a screenshot describing problem:

[image]

It's giving wrong tried location. Here's a screenshot:
`structure->module setting`  `jdk` location is

```
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67.
```

But in error it's showing other location.

Could you tell me how to solve it?

Comment: you have a fresh installation and I see new project, please try to `Build->Clean`, then `Build->Rebuild`, if doesn't work `File->Invalidate caches/Restart`

Comment: Also go to your Module settings and reselect your java directory, I mean open dialog box how would you look foe another version, but select the existing (Please watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_LxlvPAp1Q). Then `Build-> Rebuild project`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, I am doing very silly mistake. I was using proxy-server. I should use https server in-place of http server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up system level JAVA_HOME variable.

Set JAVA_HOME:

Right click My Computer and select Properties.

On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then create or edit system variable JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, for example, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02`.

Also there is PATH variable. You have to append JDK folder and JDK bin folder to that variable. For example:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02\bin
```

Note the semicolon, you have to use it to separate inputs.
After that restart your computer. After restart in CMD prompt try:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

If everything is set up succesfully output should be:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02
```

Comment: I did this. But not working. As you can see error, it's giving wrong location(Tried location). Can you tell how to change location.

Comment: Ok, pleas in your shell (command prompt) do: echo %JAVA_HOME% and give us output

Comment: One more doubt, where i have to give bin path.

Comment: here is output of echo %JAVA_HOME%" 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0.67

Comment: PATH variable, in advanced system properties, Enviroment Variables, System variables. After that do restart just to be sure

Comment: for both path, variable name will be same?

Comment: Are you using powershell for your comand prompt or CMD? echo %JAVA_HOME% gives you are configuration of system variable JAVA_HOME if it is set. Are you sure that you set JAVA_HOME variable in Enviroment variables?

Comment: yes I check both many times. You can see in error, in image. It is checking  different location. Not my jdk location. I think that is problem

Comment: @prince, here is tutorial to set system variables; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnIkVKSed4I

Comment: I restarted system. But not working. Gradle build taking infinite time. 

"Gradle: Resolve dependencies':app_releaseComiple. "

Comment: You can see my image. I am getting same error, after 20-25 min.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with JDK configuration in you project.
You can change this configuration in module settings, as explained in other stackoverflow question below

[Android Studio - supplied javaHome is not a valid folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749200/android-studio-supplied-javahome-is-not-a-valid-folder)

Comment: As I said in my problem, I did that setting, but as in error it is giving different location.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't see your comment about JDK path.

I had a similar problem with Android Studio when I changed JDK path in my project and I solved it after modify default sdk and jdk path configuration.
I followed the steps below:

Open Android Studio
Go to Quick Start -> Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure
Change the JDK location
Close and Open Andoid Studio

But I don't know if you tried this approach.

Comment: Thanks for reply but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can delete your Java from your system and reinstall the latest version.

check the folder that you've pointed to... That's the problem you got there, The Android Studio couldn't find the JDK. make sure you point Android Studio where your JDK is properly.